# In PHP how can i OR two regex in preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I want to know In PHP Can I combine below two regex in preg_replace? If yes than please explain me How that possibly make you.

```
// I want to make it one line code
$plaintext = preg_replace('/\&#x28;.*?\&#x29;/u', "", $plaintext);
$plaintext = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/u", "", $plaintext);

//Output like 
 $plaintext = preg_replace('/\&#x28;.*?\&#x29;/u' | "/\([^)]+\)/u", "", $plaintext);
```

Comment: Umm simply put the pipe symbol in between your regular expressions?

Comment: You can use preg_replace_callback for this

Comment: Have you tried with `|`: `preg_replace('/\&#x28;.*?\&#x29;|\([^)]+\)/u', "", $plaintext)`

Comment: @Justinas Yahh but doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide example input and output of `$plaintext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$plaintext = preg_replace("/(\&#x28;.*?\&#x29;)|(\([^)]+\))/u", "", $plaintext);
```